# Adding shortcut buttons to Plesk admin panel

Tags: plesk, parallels

I use Parallels Plesk Panel 11.0.9. Every time I want to check for some data I need to click the pages manually. For exaple

- To check server CPU and memory load I need to do this: Find "Server Management" in left column, click "Tools & Settings". Inside "Server Management" click "Server Information".
- Generally I use `mydomain1.com`'s `database1`. To access the database of mydomain1.com. I need find "Domains" from "Hosting services", click the domain name. Click "Websites & Domains", click "Databases", select "database1", click "Webadmin"

Is it possible to create shortcuts so I can acces them from Admin's homepage of Plesk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out direct URLs of desired actions (via page properties) and use "custom buttons" to add shortcuts. Be aware that Plesk uses frames when has left menu, so you need to watch